# how to set key by var in mongoose,Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I don't set variable the key for update, my code...

```
mongoose.model('members', Schema).update({ id: '0' }, {$push: {'this_key': 'value'}} , [], function (err, data){});
```

if I use

```
var this_key = 'test';
```

but this_key is not 'test' it's 'this_key' in

```
    mongoose.model('members', Schema).update({ id: '0' }, {$push: {this_key: 'value'}} , [], function (err, data){});
```

I need get some value ext POST[] to set variable this_key,

how to set key by variable in mongoose,Node.js?

Answer (score 13):

The syntax for string literals in object field names is biting you here. To get around it, make an intermediate object and construct it without using literals:

```
var this_key = 'test';
var push = {};
push[this_key] = 'value';   // here, it will use the variable

mongoose.model('members', Schema).update(
   { id: '0' }, {$push: push} , [], function (err, data){});
```

Comment: Helping folks out almost 6 years later!