# String Literal Issue in findOneAndUpdate Mongoose Function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

Similar to this issue [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183480/how-to-set-key-by-var-in-mongoose-node-js#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11183480/how-to-set-key-by-var-in-mongoose-node-js#_=_) I cannot get the field variable in the **findOneAndUpdate** function.  It takes it as literal field.  I tried to implement their solution but it did not work. I didn't get an error it just didn't update anything.

```
var cat = new Cat();

var field = (req.body[1].type);

Cat.findOneAndUpdate({ 'sid': req.sessionID }, {$push: {field: req.body[0]}}, {'upsert': true, 'new': true}, function (err, data){
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the bracket `[]` notation in order to set the "key" of an object property to a value from a variable:

```
var cat = new Cat();

// Just use it in the below assignment instead
//var field = (req.body[1].type);

var update = { "$push": { } };
update.$push[req.body[1].type] = req.body[0];

Cat.findOneAndUpdate(
    { 'sid': req.sessionID },
    update,                      // and reference in here
    {'upsert': true, 'new': true}, 
    function (err, data){
```

That's how to dynamically assign a key in JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, this works great.  My question is how does this work?  Why is that first part needed?  Why is it in quotes?  Any resource you have or can post would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewThreadgill What first part? All I have done is "commented out" your code so you can see what you don't need and added correct code. That's not "quotes" or needed, but just to show you what you don't need.

Comment: @AndrewThreadgill Well it's necessary to pre-declare since you cannot assign a property to something that does not exist, hence there needs to be a `$push` property already defined in the object. Python for example allows you to just chain define, but JavaScript and others do not. As for "quotes", it's just habit since serialized JSON requires quotes on key names. Plus I like people to be able to copy/paste for other languages.

Comment: @AndrewThreadgill you can have it without brackets, e.g.:

var update = { $set: {} };
update.$set[field] = newValue;